# Import data from Clio to Azure database using API v4

Tags: azure, clio-api

Let me start out by saying I am a SQL Server Database expert, not a coder so making API calls is certainly not an everyday task for me.

Having said that, I am trying to use the Azure Data Factory's data copy tool to import data from Clio to an Azure SQL Server database. I have had some limited success, data is copied over using the API and inserted into the target table but paging really seems to be an issue. I am testing this with the billable_clients call and the first 25 records with the fields I specify are inserted along with the paging record. As I understand, the billable_clients call is eligible for bulk actions which may be the solution, although I've not been able to figure out how it works. The url I am calling is below:

```
https://app.clio.com/api/v4/billable_clients.json?fields=id,unbilled_hours,name
```

Using Postman I've tried to make the same call while adding X-BULK true to the header but that returns no results. If there is anyone that can shed some light on how the X-BULK header flag is used when making a call, or if anyone has any experience loading Clio data into a SQL Server database I'd love some feedback on your methods.

If any additional information regarding my attempts or setup would help please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to download the json files with Bulk API and then update them in DB.

It isn't possible to directly insert the data